# Fast Kendall Tau in Matlab (and if necessary another language)

Tags: kendall-tau

As I understand, there are two ways to compute Kendall Tau for a data matrix $X$ (n rows of data points in $\mathbb{R}^p$):

1. corr(X,'type','kendall')
2. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27361-weighted-kendall-rank-correlation-matrix/content/kendalltau.m

The latter works very, very fast for "small" $X$ (say 300x400). But it runs out of memory when $X$ is say $100\times 1000$. Corr() works very, very slowly in this setting. It can take even an hour sometimes.

Are there any better solutions? Ideally in Matlab, but perhaps in another language?

Comment: For *unweighted* correlations, the [Wikipedia article on Kendall's tau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_rank_correlation_coefficient#Algorithms) answers this question. The `cor.fk` function in package `pcaPP` for `R` implements Simcha's algorithm and takes a fraction of a second with a $100\times 1000$ matrix. However, the link in (2) suggests a weighted version is sought.  Is that the case?

Comment: I've deleted my tentative answer. Since computing this takes a fraction of a second, I think the premises of the question, as formulated, are wrong.

Comment: So this can't work in matlab? As I understand it this is based on opaque (to me) C code.

Comment: @GregorianFunk: but the code is wrapped in a user friendly FOSS language: R.